# Error: Invalid conversion from runtime type Map<String,ANY> to List<ANY>

Tags: apex, trailhead, superbadges

While I am working on my Apex Specialist super badge, I am got this error message while I am testing my WebService class. Here is the Callout class:

```
public with sharing class WarehouseCalloutService {

private static final String WAREHOUSE_URL = 'https://th-superbadge-apex.herokuapp.com/equipment';

@future(callout=true)
public static void runWarehouseEquipmentSync(){
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(WAREHOUSE_URL);
    request.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        List<Object> results = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
        List<Product2> equipmentList = new List<Product2>();
        for(Object obj: results){
            Map<String, Object> mapJson = (Map<String, Object>)obj;
            Product2 product = new Product2();

            Integer maintenanceperiod = (Integer)mapJson.get('maintenanceperiod');               
            Integer Lifespan = (Integer)mapJson.get('lifespan');
            Integer Cost = (Integer)mapJson.get('cost');
            Boolean replacement = (Boolean)mapJson.get('replacement');
            Integer quantity = ((Integer)mapJson.get('quantity'));

            product.Replacement_Part__c = replacement;
            product.Current_Inventory__c = quantity;
            product.Name = (String)mapJson.get('name');
            product.Maintenance_Cycle__c = maintenanceperiod;
            product.Lifespan_Months__c = Lifespan;
            product.Cost__c = Cost;
            product.Warehouse_SKU__c = (String)mapJson.get('sku');
            Product.ProductCode = (String)mapJson.get('_id');
            equipmentList.add(product);
        }
        if(!equipmentList.isEmpty()){
            upsert equipmentList;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my test class:

```
@isTest
private class WarehouseCalloutServiceTest {

   @isTest static void testGetCallout() {

    Boolean expectedReplacement = false;
    String expectedName = 'Generator 3000 kW';
    String expectedSku = '100071';
    Integer expectedMaintenanceperiod = 345;
    Integer expectedLifespan = 110;
    Integer expectedCost = 5000;
    Integer expectedQuantity = 5;

    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new WarehouseCalloutServiceMock());
    Test.startTest();
    WarehouseCalloutService.runWarehouseEquipmentSync();
    Test.stopTest();

    Product2 equipment = [SELECT Id, Current_Inventory__c, Replacement_Part__c, Name, Maintenance_Cycle__c, Lifespan_Months__c, Cost__c, Warehouse_SKU__c
                          FROM Product2];
    System.assertEquals(equipment.Current_Inventory__c, expectedQuantity);                
    System.assertEquals(equipment.Replacement_Part__c, expectedReplacement);
    System.assertEquals(equipment.Name, expectedName);
    System.assertEquals(equipment.Maintenance_Cycle__c, expectedMaintenanceperiod);
    System.assertEquals(equipment.Lifespan_Months__c, expectedLifespan);
    System.assertEquals(equipment.Cost__c, expectedCost);
    System.assertEquals(equipment.Warehouse_SKU__c, expectedSku);

 }
}
```

Mock class:

```
@isTest
global class WarehouseCalloutServiceMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
// implement http mock callout

    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest request) {
    // Create a fake response
    HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    response.setBody('{"_id":"55d66226726b611100aaf744","replacement":false,"quantity":5,"name":"Generator 3000 kW","maintenanceperiod":345,"lifespan":110,"cost":5000,"sku":"100071"}');
    response.setStatusCode(200);
    return response; 
  }
}
```

Error screenshot:

[image]

This looks like pretty straight forward and I am not sure why I am seeing this error. I do not want to take someone's work and complete my badge, so trying to understand my mistake here and a possible workaround.

Comment: Do you have a time number where this error is thrown?

Comment: @ZackWalton Added the screenshot.

Comment: The problem is in your mock, I think. Can we see that?

Comment: @sfdcfox Updated with the Mock class too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is just fine, your mock class seems to be the culprit. Make sure you're returning JSON like the original, including the outer `[...]`, which makes it a list. If the first character in your JSON is `{`, it will be a `Map<String, ANY>`.

Note: Your System.assertEquals method parameters are backwards; the first value is the *expected* value, the second is the *actual* value. You'll get nonsensical errors if the test fails from the assertions otherwise.

Comment: Well, I found the mistake. yes, the mock class is the culprit.